# FastAPI + Docker: Connection refused

Tags: windows, docker, fastapi

everyone!

I am having problem deploying a FastAPI app using Docker containers.
I have tested deploying it without Docker, just using FastAPI, and all works just fine.
But when I use Docker, I am not able to access the API, getting only the "Connection refused" message.

Here it is the **Dockerfile** I am using:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /app/
COPY . /app/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get install libgomp1

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--reload"]
```

Note: the API I have to build is ML-focused, so I needed to declare some packages as above so LightGBM can be used.

After constructing the Dockerfile, I have runned the **following Docker commands**:

`docker build -t ml_app:latest .`

`docker run -p 8000:8000 --name test_cont ml_app:latest`

When I check running containers using `docker ps`, I find that the container is working fine, as the image shows:
[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjGyN.png)

Additionally, **docker logs** just return the default message of FastAPI:

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

I am trying **to access the API** using the URL that FastAPI indicates when I run the container (http://localhost:8000). I have sent requests against this URL using the browser, line commands with curl and Postman.

There are the **things I have tried to fix this issue**:

1. Change the ports.
2. With and without the command EXPOSE.
3. Running a Python script instead of using uvicorn explicitly.
4. Exposing a port different (and equal) to those declared in uvicorn argument.

So, does anyone gets what I am doing wrong? Or what I should do to access the API deployed in the container?

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't see here any information about how you're trying to access the API. Also, have you checked the container logs for any error or warnings?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will edit the question. But basically Im trying to access using either the URL that FastAPI indicates (localhost:8000) in the browser or through curl (or even using Postman), always requesting against localhost:8000

Comment: Everything here looks fine, and if I reproduce your configuration locally it works just fine (meaning that on the host I can connect to `http://localhost:8000` in the browser or via `curl` and see the expected response). Are you running under Linux, MacOS, or Windows?

Comment: Iam running on a Windows 8 machine right now

Comment: The same happens to me, but under Kubernetes. If i run the script locally, i can connect. If i run the script in Docker on my local machine, i can connect. Only running in K8s makes it fail and, what makes it really strange, it doesn’t always happen (but pretty often).

Comment: did you fixed this issue? I am facing the same problem.@MatheusRosso

Answer (score 3):

After running docker container , try `http://localhost:80` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:8000` (what's shown on docker logs).

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with my fastapi project what solution worked for me is shown below. Just run the dockerfile like this

```
sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 tagged_project_name
```

if you have not tagged the project, when building do like this and after successful build do the above command.

```
sudo docker build -f dockerfile_name -t tagged_project_name .
```